# Java video cross platform is a nightmare, is there any freedom for this?

Tags: java, c, video, jmf, fmj

What actually exist to solve Java Video ? It does not work in my linux box, JMF cant detect even my webcam. ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vic0o.png

- JMF - works in Mac, i guess no ? Cause in CentOS/Fedora it does not detects my Video camera.
- FMJ - ? Does those requires native separate installation ?
- LTI-civil ? Does those requires native separate installation ?
- Xuggler ? Does those requires native separate installation ?

My most important feature is: Can i use other java video libraries to make eye contacts video frame, means 1 screen from (Sender, Receiver, Third party) 3 to 4 participant in 1 video screen.

## Follow up:

- Java video does not work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6f5V.png
- I am now wondering so many years Java remains but Video they didnt completed yet.
- Where Adobe Flex/Air is just a few lines of code and its done (still experts dont belive in Flex/Air, i must research why, maybe quality issue and restricted raw access).
- Cant figure it out in my small brain about Java and its Video solution.
- Many more reason ... researching...

Will, Appreciate more advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMF is sadly neglected from Sun, and FMJ was started to rectify this.  I would start with FMJ and see how it works for you.

Comment: If so many steps requires to experiment, dont you think its better move to go with Flex/Air ? Its just a copy and past. Video is done.

Comment: "So many steps"?  Personally I don't believe in Flex/Air, but if it works for you, then by all means.

Comment: As JMF was neglected by Sun, so now Flex/Air is neglected by Adobe

Answer (score -1):

dsj - DirectShow is also a good choice and dont need a separate installation.

http://www.humatic.de/htools/dsj.htm